# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?

Tags: python, python-requests

The following script, which checks the status codes of a Gab user's profile, outputs an error. How can I resolve this error?

### Command to run

```
script.py -u a
```

### script.py

```
import requests, argparse
from requests import Session
session = Session()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-u','--name', required=False, default='')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
name = args['name']

data = [f"https://gab.com/{name}"]
results = []

for url in data:
    response = session.get(url)
    status_code = response.status_code
    data.append((status_code))
    print(data)
```

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\facrec\Desktop\TWITTER\Simplified\deleting.py", line 15, in <module>
    response = session.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\facrec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\facrec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\facrec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\facrec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\facrec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 390, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '200': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://200?
```

### Expected output

```
[200]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sending first request, you are adding status_code 200 to a data array. So, next iteration you are sending request to url 200

Comment: Shucks! How can I make it so that there are no iterations? Thanks!

Comment: You are adding 200 to the array, from which you are getting urls to parse. Either change the status_codes destination array, or just don't save them

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!